# Spark Column Pruning: How to prevent empty schema on count()?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I created a data source with the V2 API, and a catalog for our company internal data which works fine. When registering everything correctly and doing a

```scala
val df =
  spark
    .read
    .table("mycatalog.foo.bar")
    .select($"foo", $"bar")
```

the `pruneColumns` method in my scan builder correctly receives a schema only containing the  required `foo` and `bar` columns which is then pushed down to the `Scan`.

However, when doing:

```
logInfo(s"the count of df is ${df.count()}")
```

the `count()` operation causes an empty schema to be submitted to the `pruneColumns` method.

How do I manage to get the correct `requiredSchema` *BEFORE* `count()` makes it empty? Is there another trait I have to mix into my scan builder or elsewhere?

Comment: As far as I know, V2 data sources are leaves in the execution plan. `df.select($"foo", $"bar").count()` does not depend on the content of `foo`, nor on the content of `bar`, hence Catalyst removes them from the required schema and they never reach the reader interface.

Comment: I noticed this too when trying `SupportsPushDownAggregations` in Spark 3.2.x. The `count()` becomes `COUNT(*)` when supplied to the scan, and the pruning is never called.

Comment: Since our data source does not support push-down of `not` and `isnull` filters, as a workaround I will write into our internal documentation that for aggregations to work correctly, one should craft a `where` clause containing `not` and/or `isnull` that always evaluates to true, or using `persist()`. This will force catalyst to do the aggregation after the data was fetched from our data source.